# Can the existance of IIS be queried through Active Directory database?

Tags: active-directory, iis

I'm looking for a way to query Active Directory to return a list of IIS servers. I'm running Windows Server 2008 domain. Is there some sort of Active Directory property or attribute that gets set when IIS is installed on a server?

I know that I could query services on the servers to see if it's installed, but I'm curious if there is a way to do it strictly through Active Directory. I've looked through the database using ADSI edit (no changes made!) just to examine properties of the IIS boxes and didn't see anything jump out at me.

Anyone solved something like this before?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's nothing that does this. IIS doesn't put stuff in Active Directory, so there's nothing to query for.

Interrogating the machines directly is the only way to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can scan your internal IP ranges to see which IPs respond on port 80 (you may miss computers configured to respond on different ports). This will give you a list of web servers (IIS, Apache etc). You can improve results by requesting a page and analysing returned results (e.g. a 404 page would usually be different on different web servers). Or you can analyse HTTP headers (e.g. Server)
2. You can use SMS or SCCM to see which computers in your organisation have IIS installed.
3. You can use WMI to query computers from your AD (or a given IP range) to see if IIS is installed. E.g. http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/175977-iis-installed.html